# Understanding 'hasAttachments' Property in Graph API: Anomalies with Inline Attachments

Tags: email, outlook, microsoft-graph-api, email-attachments, inline-attachments

I'm working with the Microsoft Graph API to retrieve message details from Outlook, where I found something odd with the property "hasAttachments".

Typically, the "hasAttachments"

**is set to true :**

- when a message has one or more attachment that is not embedded within the email body

  example: [Graph API response for a message with non-inline attachment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8BRCO.png)

**is set to false in the following two scenarios:**

- when a message has no attachments

  example: [Graph API response for a message with no attachments](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ZbNa.png)
- when a message has one or more attachments and all of its attachments are embedded within the email body known as inline attachment.

  example: [Graph API response for a message with only inline attachment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q66Kj.png)

There is a property called "isInline" which is set to true if a attachment is inline.

#### **Case scenario:**

However, The response I'm getting from Graph API seems not as expected.

I encountered a scenario for a message containing an attachment that is not an inline attachment but in the Graph API response both the properties "hasAttachment" and "isInline" were false.

usually if a message has a non-inline attachment the "hasattachment" property will be true but it some of my cases it is set to be false. I have attached the copy of my response in a link below

```
{
    "@odata.etag" : "W/\"CQAAABYAAABEIDZQDkY9Q11HVLaaS/ZVAAEWzqBC\"",
    "id": "AAMkADk40TYXNzhjLWE5yzgtNGE5N..."
    "hasAttachments": false,
    "attachments": [
        {
            "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.fileAttachment",
            "@odata.mediaContentType": "application/x-microsoft-rpmsg-message",
            "id": "AAMkADk40TYXNzhjLWE5yzgtNGE5NS1hYTd1LT1iZELuw="
            "lastModifiedDateTime": "2023-06-22T09:57:48z",
            "name": "message_v2.rpmsg",
            "contentType": "application/x-microsoft-rpmsg-message",
            "size": 118679,
            "islnline": false,
            "contentld": "21672D7F295E8B4D9e9C6CBD4E7EIBCB@1NDPRDØ1.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM",
            "contentLocation": null,
            "contentBytes": "qne533e9362efp6d/124Y7fJOK/QgvBg....."
```

[image]

**The query I used in Graph explorer:**

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/mailFolders/Inbox/messages?$select=hasAttachments&$expand=attachments
```

I would appreciate any guidance on what I might be missing or if there's something I'm doing wrong. Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That attachment is listed as an `application/x-microsoft-rpmsg-message` which (if you had the "raw" e-mail in its orignal MIME format instead of MS Graph's JSON representation) [would be an "Alternative View" of the body of this MIME e-mail](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME#alternative) - which is why it isn't considered an "attachment" by the MS Graph.

Comment: Thank you @Dai, the answer really helped. While I was checking the messages with the case I mentioned above in my question, I found many messages with attachment content-type : **'application/pkcs-7-mime', 'Multipart/signed', 'message/rfc822'**. Here the **'message/rfc822'** seems to appear for Non-delivery reports and Delivery receipt message but I have no clue regarding **'application/pkcs-7-mime', 'Multipart/signed'**.  it would be helpful if I know the reason for these properties and other properties that could make the MS Graph not to consider it as an attachment.